# ASP.NET Gridview paging not retaining when we come back from another page using browser back button

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview, paging, scriptmanager

I have a gridview on my ASP.NET application, I have set AutoGenerateColumns = false and programatically populating it. This gridview is in updatepanel Sorting and paging working fine. I have no issues with that. I have another page which is navigated on click of a particular column of this gridview and it shows more information of a record like master-detail. When browser back button is pressed, it goes on page one. I want it to remember the page I went from.

I have been searching for last 3 days. I have implented AddHistoryPoint, but its not working.

```
 protected void detailsGrid_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ScriptManager1.IsInAsyncPostBack && !ScriptManager1.IsNavigating)
    {
        ScriptManager1.AddHistoryPoint("page", detailsGrid.PageIndex.ToString());
    }
}
protected void ScriptManager1_Navigate(object sender, HistoryEventArgs e)
{
    string indexPage = e.State["page"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(indexPage))
    {
        detailsGrid.PageIndex = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int pageNo = Convert.ToInt16(indexPage);
        detailsGrid.PageIndex = pageNo;
        loadmainGrid();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int pageNo = Convert.ToInt16(indexPage);
loadmainGrid();
detailsGrid.PageIndex = pageNo;
```